# How to align items in dropdown menu with my parent menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to align my MENU and PROMOTION dropdowns correctly.

My navigation bar is fixed to the top so even when scrolling down it will still be there.

I only had this problem when I added `text-align:center`to my `ul.topnav`class.

I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 for these codes. I use the Fluid Grid Layout by this software but the Navigation Bar has nothing to do with this and so I am missing some other CSS and JS files given by this layout like boilerplate.css and respondmin.js.

To visualize my problem:

[image: Image of the problem]

What I really want is to get the items in dropdown to be align directly underneath the PROMOTIONS in a single line.

P/S: I used a responsive Navigation Bar so please enlarge the browser to view the problem which only occur when it's fullscreen.

My codes are as following:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 0;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  text-align:center;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 13.75px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #F00;}

ul.topnav li.dropdown {
 display: inline-block;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 text-align:center;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content a{
 color: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #999;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.topnav li {
 width: 19%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
}

/*Footer CSS*/

body{
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper{
 padding:20px;
 height:auto;
}

footer{
 background-color:#666;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:17.75px;
    font-weight:bold;
 align-self: flex-end;
 line-height: 3;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

footer img{
 width:42px;
 height: 42px;
 margin: 0 1em;
}

hr{
 width:100%;
}

footer p{white-space:pre;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="_css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="_css/fluid-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="_css/headfoot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="_script/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="_script/headfoot.js"></script>
</head>
  
<html>
  
<body>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">MENU</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Appetizer</a>
      <a href="#">Main Course</a>
      <a href="#">Dessert</a>
      <a href="#">Soup</a>
      <a href="#">Drinks</a>
      <a href="#">Side Snacks</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">PROMOTIONS</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Breakfast</a>
      <a href="#">Lunch</a>
      <a href="#">Dinner</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "header"</div>
  <div id="maincontent">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "maincontent"</div>
  <div id="food1">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "food1"</div>
  <div id="food2">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "food2"</div>
  <div id="food3">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "food3"</div>
  <div id="content">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "content"</div>
</div>

<footer>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/icon-twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/YouTube-icon-full_color.png" alt="YouTube"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/original_instagram-circle-icon.png" alt="Instagram"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/tumblr-logo-icon-8.png" alt="Tumblr"/>
    <img src="Social%20Media%20Icons/google-plus-icon.png" alt="GooglePlus"/>
    <hr>
    <p>S   T   A   Y       C   O   N   N   E   C   T   E   D</p>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `display: block` to your menu links, and i add 'position: relative' to your menu li for using `left: 0` on `.dropdown-content`. Also i changed `.dropdown-content` width to `100%`.

So change your css like this:

```
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 0;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  text-align:center;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
  display: block; /* change */
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 13.75px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #F00;}

ul.topnav li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; /* Change */
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    /* min-width: 160px; Change */
    width: 100%; /* Change */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align:center;
    left: 0; /* Change */
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content a{
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  ul.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content{
    width: auto;
    min-width: 160px;
    left: 0;
  }

  ul.topnav li.dropdown{
    position: static;
  }
}

.topnav li {
    width: 19%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Footer CSS*/

body{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper{
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
}

footer{
    background-color:#666;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:17.75px;
    font-weight:bold;
    align-self: flex-end;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

footer img{
    width:42px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

hr{
    width:100%;
}

footer p{white-space:pre;}
```

Live: https://jsfiddle.net/9rwvsso5/

Comment: It looks good on fullscreen but since its a responsive navbar, once the browser is resized, the dropdown is pushed out of view.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that your hover state topline nav change is applied to the *a*, but the dropdown is aligned with the *li* element.

You'll want to adjust the padding and hover states so they apply to the li element, not the a tag — that should solve your issues!

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty new to html and css, need to learn more in-depth about these things. BTW, thanks :)

Comment: Raika, please note that you should give an upvote to answers that were of help to you.